DQL query : LOWER function suddenly stopped working
Recently updated a backend service from a Symfony 5.4 / php 7 to a Symfony 6.4 / php 8.3 config.
The database is using Postgresql 14.
Since the doctrine queries I have that include LOWER stopped working, for instance:
$qb->where('i.title ' . 'LIKE LOWER(:keyWord)')
I wrapped them in a try / catch but I don't even have an error coming, just no response at all (another error introduced on purpose, like a misspell does send back an error).
As soon as I just remove the "LOWER" everything works fine. Seems like just the fact it's written in the query blocks everything.
I must underline that it's not similar to other cases I saw where LOWER is written but has no effect, in my case it's like it's stopping the whole process, nothing happens like the query isn't sent.
I updated the database to  Postgresql 17 but it had no effect.
Any help would... help!
Thanks

Upgrade to Postgresql 17
Clear various caches
Try the SQL request directly in the database adminer (it works)
Try the solution from "Doctrine Query Builder LOWER not working"


If you aren't getting errors, it's always possible that the function is correct, just not getting the expected matches. Can you please check the generated SQL?

Hi Alvaro
Thanks for your message.
I cannot even get the generated SQL when LOWER is written, I do get it when I remove it, it's like nothing happens when it's there

That suggests you may be getting some Doctrine exception and a 500 Internal Server Error status returned by web server, and your environment is not configured to show errors. Have you checked the log files for errors?

Hi Alvaro
Thanks for your reply. The problem is gone on my side, I updated all the packages I could in my app, including doctrine/orm, and it seems to have solved it
